# Having performance issue using tmi.js (Twitch Messaging Interface) to get live chat messages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The first thing I noticed was that there was no need to render message lines the moment I received it from the tmi.js. So I just buffered and batched the message updates for every 100ms, but that did not fix the performance issue

vuejs dev tool performance frames per seconds

[image: vuejs dev tool performance frames per seconds]

vuejs dev tool performance component render]

[image: vuejs dev tool performance component render]

It could be many reactive data can make the v-for slower and cause poor performance? Even if that was true, it would make my website harder to maintain if I go for vanilla js. So if anyone can push me to right direction to go from there it will help me greatly.

```html
<template>
    <div ref="messages" class="message default-scroll overflow-auto">
      <div
        v-for="({ id, login, displayName, badges, color, msg }) in messages"
        :key="id"
        class="d-flex border-top pt-1 pl-2"
      >
        <div v-if="badges">
          <b-avatar
            v-if="badges['clip-champ']"
            :src="globalBadges['clip-champ'].versions[badges['clip-champ']].image_url_4x"
            class="mr-2"
            variant="primary"
          />
          <b-avatar
            v-else-if="badges.broadcaster"
            :src="globalBadges.broadcaster.versions[badges.broadcaster].image_url_4x"
            class="mr-2"
            variant="primary"
          />
          <b-avatar
            v-else-if="badges.moderator"
            :src="globalBadges.moderator.versions[badges.moderator].image_url_4x"
            class="mr-2"
            variant="primary"
          />
          <b-avatar
            v-else-if="badges.subscriber"
            :src="channelBadges.subscriber.versions[badges.subscriber].image_url_4x"
            class="mr-2"
            variant="primary"
          />
          <b-avatar v-else class="mr-2" variant="primary" />
        </div>
        <b-avatar v-else class="mr-2" variant="primary" />
        <div class="w-100">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <nuxt-link :to="`/${login}`" class="text-decoration-none">
              <b-badge
                class="rounded-pill f-14 mr-1"
                :style="`background-color: ${color};`"
              >
                {{ displayName }}
              </b-badge>
            </nuxt-link>
          </div>
          <p>{{ msg }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
  props: {
    broadcaster: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
    globalBadges: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
    channelBadges: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      batchMessages: [],
      messages: []
    };
  },
  mounted () {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.messages.push(...this.batchMessages);
      this.batchMessages = [];
    }, 100);
  },
  async created () {
    this.client = new tmi.Client({
      connection: {
        reconnect: true,
        secure: true
      },
      identity: {
        username: this.$auth.user.login,
        password: `oauth:${this.$auth.$storage.getUniversal("_token.social")}`
      },
      channels: [ this.broadcaster.login ]
    });

    this.client.connect().catch((err) => {
      // send error to sentry
      console.log(err);
    });

    this.client.on("message", (channel, userstate, msg, self) => {
      if (this.messages.length >= 150) {
        // I used Array.shift() to remove the first at 150 array length but still have frames drop
        // If anyone can give me a better suggestion it will help thanks
        // this.messages.shift();
      }
      this.batchMessages.push({
        id: userstate.id,
        login: userstate.username,
        displayName: userstate["display-name"],
        badges: userstate.badges,
        color: userstate.color,
        emotes: userstate.emotes,
        msg
      });
    });
  },
```

Comment: How many messages are received at a time?  How many messages are batched every 100ms into the `messages` array?  Vue normally doesn't have perf issues like this, but there can be problems with v-for and the :key.

Comment: Might help to also drop an example of userstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do a little digging on this, since it seems like an interesting problem.  And I realized that it very much is an interesting problem.

It turns out, `v-for` performance is a somewhat known issue.  [Here's](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2000) an issue talking about it.  That issue mostly talks about how reactive properties, like v-model, can cause serious problems with the performance.

However, one of the recommendations was to use a virtual scroller, and I can't agree more with that recommendation.  [Here](https://akryum.github.io/vue-virtual-scroller/#/chat) is an example of a library that can be used for exactly this.  It recycles your components so that you're not creating hundreds of rows of unique items that are off screen.

I was able to reproduce your performance problems with a for-loop, adding 10 items to the Dom every 100ms.  This would give me around ~200ms rendering latency, and usually dropped down to about 20-30 fps, which is about what you had.

Using this library, I was able to add thousands of messages per second, while keeping 50+ FPS.

Fair warning, this was the first library I looked at, and it doesn't seem to be the most actively maintained.

I won't go over any code examples, since they are somewhat involved, but you can find the component documentation I used [here](https://akryum.github.io/vue-virtual-scroller/#/chat).  Just a heads up, this requires that you know the size of your chat items up front.  If not, there's also a DynamicScroller.